# Cross-browser solution to remove browser default focus styles

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser, focus

Is there any cross-browser way to remove the browser's styles for focused elements?

If not, what are the styles that the most used browsers apply?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to remove?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, set `outline` style to `0` on elements `:focus` selector. For example:

```
:focus{
   outline:0;
}
```

Should work in IE,Opera,Chrome,FF,Safari ...

**Note**: For `:focus` and `outline` to work in IE8, a `DOCTYPE` must be declared - `<!DOCTYPE html>` in first html document line.

Edited: Seems that `none` works, but `0` is more common way.